# terminate command execution

Tags: powershell, go, exec

I want to execute powershell commands using the `exec.Command()` function, and I also want to be able to stop/terminate command execution at any point.

```
cmd := exec.Command("powershell.exe", "-Command", "ping -n 50 google.com")
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    HideWindow: true,
}
cmd.Start()
```

This pings google.com 50 times, in a powershell window I can easily stop it by hitting `ctrl + C` but in GO I can't figure a way to do it.
I've seen other people facing this problem and they often seem to mark a correct answer which uses a for loop and a switch inside of it which if receive data from a channel it exits. The problem is that this doesn't work and I don't see how it's supposed to. But the most common thing I've seen which is the most obvious is using `cmd.Process.Kill()` or `cmd.Process.Signal(syscall.SIGKILL)` but non of them work aswell.

Here's example of the first method I was talking about:
customOutput just prints live output to the screen

```
func main() {
    stopChan := make(chan struct{})

    go runUntilStopped(stopChan)

    time.Sleep(3 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Sending stop signal...")
    stopChan <- struct{}{}
    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    close(stopChan)

    time.Sleep(1 * time.Second)
    fmt.Println("Program finished.")

    for { // Stops main from exiting to see if the pings still go through
        
    }
}

type customOutput struct{
}

func (c customOutput) Write(b []byte) (int, error) {
    fmt.Println(string(b))
    return len(b), nil
}


func runUntilStopped(stopChan chan struct{}) {
    fmt.Println("Routine started.")
    for {
        select {
        case <-stopChan:
            fmt.Println("ROUTINE STOPPED")
            return
        default:
            cmd := exec.Command("powershell.exe", "-Command", "ping -n 50 google.com")
            cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
                HideWindow: true,
            }
            cmd.Stdout = customOutput{}
            cmd.Run()
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the other one:
This line `count >= 15 && count <= 20` is used to kill the process after like the 5th ping and then continue to run the program to see if it still pings or not

```
func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("powershell", "-nologo")

    stdin, err := cmd.StdinPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    stdout, err := cmd.StdoutPipe()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    cmd.Start()

    log.Println("[+] Proccess created with PID:", cmd.Process.Pid)

    fmt.Fprintln(stdin, "ping -n 50 google.com")
    stdin.Close()

    count := 0
    buf := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := stdout.Read(buf)
        if err == io.EOF {
            break // End of output
        }
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        fmt.Print(string(buf[:n]))
        count += 1

        if count >= 15 && count <= 20 {
            fmt.Println("[!] Process killed")
            cmd.Process.Kill()
        }
    }

    stdout.Close()
}
```

Comment: Your command is spawning another subprocess, so any signals are received by the `powershell`, not `ping`. Can you remove the extra shell from the process?

Comment: When using Start (as opposed to Run), Wait *must* be called eventually, otherwise the process doesn't terminate properly. This is mentioned in [the docs for Start](https://pkg.go.dev/os/exec#Cmd.Start).

Comment: Also, do not close stdout yourself. Wait will handle that. See docs for StdoutPipe.

Comment: @JimB Thank you, I've never realized that I knew it had to be a dumb mistake. But I do want to execute those commands in PowerShell so that the syntax works and things like echo work aswell. Is there no way to send `ctrl + C` signal to the PowerShell process, how can I achieve this?

Comment: @Peter Thank you, I will adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: @Niu, I don't really know windows, but I thought that the shell acted like a unix process group by default. Maybe try sending `os.Interrupt` to the process instead?